# SQL Query to return the first row and only the first row that satisfies a condition

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a table of randomly generated keys that I want to use as registration keys for my website.

The table layout is as follows:

```
id|     regkey         |inUse

1 |nxwn362oe6jn4ses8psl|y
2 |nmin875euytoises7sil|n
```

I need to return the first row that satisfied the condition n for the inuse column.

How can I tailor my query to only pull one row? So far I obviously have:

```
Select `regkey` FROM `database` WHERE `inUse` = n
```

but where do I go from here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which DBMS mysql/sqlserver? Both are different .

Comment: I know I was pretty surprised myself. A little embarrassed tbh xD.

Comment: Everyone using a `LIMIT` or `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is not returning consistent rows every time. Please do you the `ORDER BY` clause in your query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use limit

```
Select regkey FROM database WHERE inUse = n limit 1
```

Comment: Wow, I totally knew this too....It's 4 A.M here...probably need another cup of coffee. Anyways I appreciate it!

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless. Abhik should know better!

Answer (score 1):

In MYSQL it would be

```
Select `regkey` FROM `database` WHERE `inUse` = n limit 1
```

and in SQL server

```
Select top 1 `regkey` FROM `database` WHERE `inUse` = n
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `mysql` you can use limit:

```
Select `regkey` FROM `database` WHERE `inUse` = n order by id limit 1
```

if you use `sql-server` you can use `top`

```
Select top 1 `regkey` FROM `database` WHERE `inUse` = n order by id
```

Comment: ...and hope that regkey isn't indexed